# Find maximum of integral

Tags: integration, optimization

I am trying to find the maximum value of

$$I=\int_0^y \sqrt{x^4+(y-y^2)^2}\,dx$$

for $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

At $y=1$ the value $I=1/3$ which I think is the answer. How can you prove this?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to find the derivative of $I(y)$.